# How can I make Windows 8.1 NOT sync across devices?

Tags: sync, windows-8.1, microsoft-account

I was wondering if there is a setting somewhere that will let me make Windows 8.1 *not* sync things like wallpapers, lock screens, and such across multiple devices with the same MS account.

I have a laptop and desktop that I am signed into with the same account and when I change something on the laptop, it automatically changes on the desktop as well, and vice versa. It is a minor annoyance, but it would be nice if it were fixable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(skydrive is now called OneDrive)

**To choose which settings to sync**:

Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)

Tap or click SkyDrive, and then tap or click Sync settings.

Under the different settings categories, turn off the settings you no longer want to sync.

**To Stop sync for all settings:**
Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)

Tap or click SkyDrive, and then tap or click Sync settings.

Under the Sync settings with SkyDrive heading, turn off Sync your settings on this PC.